# Proof Involving Imaginary Number: Where's the wrong one?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

Here are the propositions:

$$i=\sqrt{-1}$$
$$i^2=-1$$
$$(i)(i)=-1$$
$$\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=-1$$
$$\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=-1$$
$$\sqrt{1}=-1$$

There's an error in the propositions above. I think it's in the fifth line where $\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=-1$.

Are $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ and $a=(\sqrt{a})(\sqrt{a})$ different from each other?

Comment: You have identified the correct line.   When we take the square root, we have defined the operation to always be the positive root.  While $x^2 = 1$ has two solutions, $\sqrt {x^2} = |x|$

Comment: I think this is among the most frequently asked questions.

Comment: @DougM wouldn't that make both 5 and 6 wrong?

Comment: @qbert 6 is wrong, but it logically follows from 5, carrying along the same error.

Answer (score 1):

1) The rule "$\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}= \sqrt{ab}$" is not true for a and b non-real.

2) As Elio Joseph said, **defining** "i" as "$\sqrt{-1}$ is not rigorous.  Better is to define the complex numbers to b **pairs** of real numbers with addition defined by (a, b)+ (c, d)= (a+ c, b+ d) and multiplication by (a, b)x(c, d)= (ac- bd, ad+ bc).  We think of the real numbers as "embedded" in the complex numbers by a<==> (a, 0).  The "imaginary numbers" are the set of pairs (0, b).  And, of course, "i" is (0, 1):  (0, 1)x(0, 1)= (0x0- 1x1, 0x1+ 1x0)= (-1, 0) which is what we associate with "-1".

Answer (score 0):

Both 5 and 6 are wrong, assuming the usual choice of positive square root. In order to make 
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x} $$
a bonafide function, mathematicians have defined it to output the positive square root. By this logic, both 5 and 6 are wrong, as they select the negative square root.

Answer (score -1):

The error is that you can't say that $$i=\sqrt{-1}$$

because the function $\sqrt.$ is not defined on $\mathbb C$ properly.

You can't assigned a unique value for $\sqrt{z}$ if $z\in \mathbb C$ like you do for real positive numbers.

Therefore, writing $\sqrt{-1}$ instead of $i$ may and will lead to wrong results.

Comment: You have to be a bit careful with stating this. Often $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is defined to be single-valued so that it is indeed a function. It is the difference between $\sqrt{\cdot}$ and $\cdot^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: $i$ can be defined as one of the roots of $\sqrt{-1}$